# You are my forever kind of love, a love for the soul that can never die. - which is being modified? love or soul

Tags: relative-clauses

- You are my forever kind of love, a love for the soul that can never die.

what is the relative clause *(that can never die)* modifying? Love or Soul.
I think the relative clause is modifying 'Love', but there's an argument to be made for the relative clause modifying "soul" as well.

Comment: It means the love that can never die (regardless of what a soul might do). It emphasises what the first part of the sentence says: *my forever kind of love*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's ambiguous.  It could be read both ways.  But the text is not the kind of text that needs a single interpretation. It is not a legal contract. The ambiguity might be deliberate (with both meanings intended) or not.